# React Native Flatlist won't render item's width dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to create a messaging interface using a flatlist and a message bubble style from the ui kit nachos-ui, but I am having trouble getting the flatlist to render different widths of the text bubbles based on the amount of text.  Whenever I first send a message, the bubble seems to be a decent width:

[image]

However whenever I send another message, although its hard to see in these pictures, it changes the width of the previous message and constricts the new message to what seems to be a maximum width

[image]

Here is my code for the flatlist:

```
<FlatList
          data={this.state.messages}
          style={{marginLeft: 280}}
          ref={ref => this.flatList = ref}
          onContentSizeChange={() => this.flatList.scrollToEnd({animated: true})}
          onLayout={() => this.flatList.scrollToEnd({animated:true})}
          keyExtractor = {item => item.timestamp}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Bubble style={{marginTop: 20}} color="#FFC800"
           >{item.contents}</Bubble>}
        />
```

Also the code for the whole component might be helpful to diagnose the problem:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} 
      behavior="padding"
      keyboardVerticalOffset={64}>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.inputContainer}>

      <FlatList
          data={this.state.messages}
          style={{marginLeft: 280}}
          ref={ref => this.flatList = ref}
          onContentSizeChange={() => this.flatList.scrollToEnd({animated: true})}
          onLayout={() => this.flatList.scrollToEnd({animated:true})}
          keyExtractor = {item => item.timestamp}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Bubble style={{marginTop: 20}} color="#FFC800"
           >{item.contents}</Bubble>}
        />
      <View style={{flexDirection:'row', backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}>
      <Input
        containerStyle={{marginVertical: 10, width:300, marginLeft: 20}}
        inputStyle={styles.textInput}
        keyboardAppearance="dark"
        placeholder=""
        autoCorrect={false}
        onChangeText={(message) => { this.setState({message})}}
        value={this.state.message}
        />
        <Button 
          buttonStyle={{borderRadius: 25, marginTop: 40, marginLeft: 10, paddingVertical: 5, backgroundColor: "#9214FF"}}
          icon={{name: 'arrow-up', type: 'feather', color:'white'}}
          onPress={()=>{Keyboard.dismiss; this.onPressButton()}} 
          title=""/> 
        </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

How do I get the flatlist to render each message with a dynamic size based on the amount of text submitted without changing any previous messages, and without a predetermined maximum width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your FlatList style :

`style={{marginLeft: 280}}`

It "compressed" all your items on the right, always with se same width.

A better way is to remove this marginLeft and align the bubbles on the right with :

`<FlatList style= {{ alignItems: 'flex-end' }} ...>`

Comment: That seems to have only made the messages stretch the entire width of the screen, and they also only have one size, that being the screen width.  Whenever I try to place message bubbles within the view outside of a flatlist the width corresponds to the amount of text, however within the flatlist it only seems to have a fixed size, or the size of previous messages changes with each new message.

Comment: Ok, can you try 
`<Bubble style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-end', marginTop: 20}} color="#FFC800" >{item.contents}</Bubble>}`
(still without the marginLeft)

Comment: Wow that worked perfectly thank you! Sorry to keep bugging you, but do you also know of a way to set a maximum width for the bubbles?

Comment: `<Bubble  style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-end', marginTop: 20, maxWidth:100 }}>`

Comment: Didn't think it was that simple haha, your help is much appreciated.